# Representations of direct products of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products

Each irreducible representation of $G_1 \times G_2$ is isomorphic to a
representation $\rho^1 \otimes \rho^2$, where $\rho^i$ is an irreducible representation of $G_i$ ($i = 1,2$).

Can we extend this result to reducible representations? That is, can we say, for each representation $\pi: G_1 \times G_2 \to GL(V)$, there exist $\rho^1: G_1 \to GL(V_1)$ and $\rho^2: G_2 \to GL(V_2)$ such that $V$ and $\pi$ are isomorphic to $V_1 \otimes V_2$ and $\rho^1 \otimes \rho^2$, respectively?

If this is not true in general, will be a restriction on $G_1$ and $G_2$ to make the statement true?

Comment: Given an understanding of how reps are direct sums of irreps, and irreps of direct products are tensor products of irreps, this is kind of like asking if any polynomial $f(x,y)$ can be factored as $g(x)h(y)$. The counterexample in my answer is kind of like the polynomial $x+y$ in that regard.

Comment: Maybe just to emphasize there is nothing sophisticated going on here, if $V_1$ is an irreducible representation of $G_1$, and $V_2$ is an irreducible representation of $G_2$, then $V_1\oplus V_2$ is a representation of $G_1\times G_2$ (where $G_i$ acts trivially on $V_{3-i}$) which cannot be written in the form you propose. At least in the semisimple case, however, the only issue is that direct sums of tensor products are not in general tensor products.

Comment: It's worth noting that @coiso's comment does not apply generally, but it does apply in two important cases: (1.) when the groups are finite-dimensional and the representations are over $\mathbb{F}$-vector fields, where moreover the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}$ doesn't divide the group's order, and also (2.) when the groups in question are in fact semisimple Lie algebras and the representation is finite-dimensional, over a characteristic zero field (such as the reals or the complex numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume we're talking about the semisimple case, e.g. finite groups and complex vector spaces.

Any $(G_1\times G_2)$-rep will be a direct sum of irreps; you just described the irreps. Such reps generally won't be "factorizable" as a tensor product. No condition can change this besides triviality. E.g. if $V_1,V_2$ are irreps and $W_1,W_2$ are trivial reps of $G_1,G_2$ (resp),

$$ V\,=\,(V_1\otimes W_2)\,\oplus\,(W_1\otimes V_2) $$

is not equivalent to $U_1\otimes U_2$ for any $G_1$-rep $U_1$ and $G_2$-rep $U_2$.

*Proof by contradiction*. You could write $U_1,U_2$ themselves as direct sums, and then distribute the tensor product $U_1\otimes U_2$ over the direct sums - counting irreps we see either $U_1$ has two irreps and $U_2$ has one or vice versa, wlog assume the former $U_1=U_1'\oplus U_2''$, and so

$$ V \,\cong\,(U_1'\otimes U_2)\,\oplus\,(U_1''\otimes U_2), $$

which (because multiplicity of irreps is unique) means $U_2\cong W_2\cong V_2$, contra hypothesis.

---

Here's an advanced perspective.

The $G$-reps, up to isomorphism, equipped with direct sum and tensor, form a *semiring* $(\mathrm{Rep}(G),\oplus,\otimes)$, like the natural numbers $(\mathbb{N},+,\times)$. If we allow formal differences ("virtual" reps) we get the **Burnside ring** $\mathrm{Burn}(G)$ (just like how we construct $\mathbb{Z}$ out of $\mathbb{N}$). The irreps form a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $\mathrm{Burn}(G)$ as an additive group. The result you cite implies

$$\mathrm{Burn}(G_1\times G_2)\cong\mathrm{Burn}(G_1)\otimes\mathrm{Burn}(G_2) $$

as rings. You (kind of) just asked if every element of the latter is a "simple" tensor.

Comment: I do not understand your counterexample. Since $\mathbb{C}\otimes V_2 \cong V_2\otimes\mathbb{C}$, . $V\, \cong (V_1\otimes\mathbb{C})\,\oplus\,(V_2 \otimes\mathbb{C})$ and $U_2=\mathbb{C}$. Isn't it right?

Comment: The first two are *technically* right, tensoring $(G_1\otimes G_2)$-reps together, but misleading. They do not imply $U_2=\Bbb C$ because $V_2\otimes\Bbb C$ is not of the form ($G_1$-irrep) $\otimes$ ($G_2$-irrep). You've shown my counterexample can be factored as $(V_1\oplus V_2)\otimes\Bbb C$, but this is a tensor of $(G_1\otimes G_2)$-reps which is not of the form ($G_1$-rep) $\otimes$ ($G_2$-rep). Keeping $G_1$-reps on the left and $G_2$-reps on the right of $\otimes$ will avoid this mistake. I edited my answer to more clearly distinguish the trivial reps, too.

Answer (score 2):

For such a basic question, a “low-tech” explicit counterexample seems more appropriate. Let $G\cong C_2$ be the cyclic group of order $2$ and $\mathrm{Irr}(G)=\{1_G,\lambda\}$. Suppose that $1_G\otimes\lambda+\lambda\otimes 1_G=\alpha\otimes\beta$ for characters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $G$. Without loss of generality, $\alpha(1)=2$ and $\beta(1)=1$. Since $1_G\otimes\lambda\ne \lambda\otimes 1_G$, we must have $\alpha=1_G+\lambda$. But then,
$$\alpha\otimes\beta=1_G\otimes 1_G+\lambda\otimes 1_G\qquad \text{ or } \qquad \alpha\otimes\beta=1_G\otimes\lambda+\lambda\otimes\lambda.$$

Comment: What do you mean by the numbers 1 and 2 in $\alpha(1)=2$?

Comment: These are the degrees of the characters/representations. By definition $\alpha(1)$ is the trace of the identity matrix.